# change text color only of user entered string in AJAX extended textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, vb.net

I am extending a texbox control with AJAX Autocomplete and I have successfully implemeted an autocomplete text box where once the user enters 3 characters my database returns a list of records that begin with the first 3 characters entered by the user.

I then changed this feature to use some Fuzzy logic so that the strings that returned contain no less than the 3 characters entered by the user and progressively becomes a shorter more refined list as the user enters a more specific search string.

I then used the inlcluded CSS class of the Autocomplete control to change the backgorund color and selected item color in the extended texbox.

```
            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender 
                ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" 
                runat="server" 
                DelimiterCharacters="" 
                Enabled="True" 
                EnableCaching="True" 
                ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
                ServicePath="~/search/strngSrch.asmx" 
                TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
                UseContextKey="True" 
                CompletionSetCount="30" 
                CompletionInterval="10"
                MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                CompletionListItemCssClass="itemHighlighted" 
                CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemHighlighted1">                    
            </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**What I would like to do now is change the color of the text ONLY in each string (list item) that matches what the user is entering after 3 or more characters have been entered.**

I have been searching for something like this on the web for 2 days and have not found a similar solution. My efforts have become more than frustrating.

User Enters:  fish

Results list should look like:

```
Fishing      (The 4 letters = to Fish should be red in each of these list items)

New Fishing licenses

Renew Fishing License

Fish and hatchery lists
```

If anyone has any links or similar type of solution I would be very pleased to look it over.

This functionality could best be compared to searching for a text string in a PDF where the word background is highlighted yellow for each occurance within the doc. I don't care if it turns the background a different color ONLY behind the text the user entered, or changes the text color.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank the link below for providing a solution to the question. I finally found something that almost worked. In the interest of not posting only a link, please review the working code below.

Note some of my minor changes in the below code over the original found in the link at the end.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

function aceSelected(sender, e) {

    var value = e._item.innerText;       //  get_text();           

    if (!value) {
        if (e._item.parentElement && e._item.parentElement.tagName == "LI")
                    value = e._item.parentElement.attributes["_innerText"].value;
        else if (e._item.parentElement && e._item.parentElement.parentElement.tagName == "LI")
                    value = e._item.parentElement.parentElement.attributes["_innerText"].value;
        else if (e._item.parentNode && e._item.parentNode.tagName == "LI")
            value = e._item.parentNode._value;
        else if (e._item.parentNode && e._item.parentNode.parentNode.tagName == "LI")
                    value = e._item.parentNode.parentNode._innerText;
        else value = "";
    }

    var searchText = $get('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;

    searchText = searchText.replace('null', '');
    sender.get_element().value = value;
}

function acePopulated(sender, e) {

    //Give BehaviourId here
    var behavior = $find('AutoCompleteEx');
    var target = behavior.get_completionList();

    if (behavior._currentPrefix != null) {

        var prefix = behavior._currentPrefix.toLowerCase();
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < target.childNodes.length; i++) {

            var sValue = target.childNodes[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase();

            if (sValue.indexOf(prefix) != -1) {
                var fstr = target.childNodes[i].innerHTML.substring(0, sValue.indexOf(prefix));
                var pstr = target.childNodes[i].innerHTML.substring(fstr.length, fstr.length + prefix.length);
                var estr = target.childNodes[i].innerHTML.substring(fstr.length + prefix.length, target.childNodes[i].innerHTML.length);                    
                target.childNodes[i].innerHTML = "<div class='autocomplete-item'>" + fstr + '<B><font color=red>' + pstr + '</font></B>' + estr + "</div>";
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

On your AutoComplete Extender provide the following values....

```
BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"  
OnClientPopulated="acePopulated"
OnClientItemSelected="aceSelected"
```

That is about it, I had to perform some minor changes and debugging. Like the closing java script tag is wrong, and the function to get the value from the textbox did not work with e.get_value() so I changed it to e._item.innerText and seem to be working just fine.

[Source of Solution](http://www.techtasks.net/2011/03/how-to-display-prefixtext-in-different.html)